# Can we monitor for a particular text like (Name=abc) in API response and get notified in Postman?

Tags: api, postman, monitoring, web-api-testing

API Testing:
Currently, I am using Postman to test API response
I want to monitor a particular text in API response and get notified for example-

```
{
    "productname": "PARLE",


    "customer": "ABC",
}
```

If I get a customer name in the API response as ABC I want to get notified through mail or slack or anything.

Is this possible? if Yes please share me the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

you can run periodic tests with a software like [Overseer](https://github.com/cmaster11/overseer), and receive notifications using a [Notify17](https://notify17.net) notification template (see the sample [recipe](https://notify17.net/recipes/overseer/)).

You could use a test rule like:

```
http://myurl.com/path must run http with not-content '"customer": "ABC"'
```

To have an easy start with Overseer, you can check out the [Kubernetes deployment example](https://github.com/cmaster11/overseer/tree/master/example-kubernetes).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your use case using Postman Monitors to send an email or send a slack message by following these steps:

1. Configure your monitor to run with an environment. (Reference: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/monitors/intro_monitors/)
2. In the test script of your Collection's Request, fetch the response using `pm.response.json()` (Based on the response structure you mentioned)
3. Use the following code snippet to determine whether the response contains what you need:

   ```js
   if (pm.response.json().customer === 'ABC') {
       // no op
   }
   else {
       postman.setNextRequest(null);
   }
   ```

   Here, if the condition is not met, then the next request that will be executed is `null`, which means that the collection execution will stop here. However, if the condition is met, this will not be set and the next request will be executed.
4. You can use various Public APIs to achieve tasks like send an email or send a slack message:

   [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api) | [Slack API](https://api.slack.com/)

   Create a request below the current request titled 'Send notification'. Use the documentation provided to set the request up.
5. When your monitor runs, if the condition is not met, then `postman.setNextRequest` will be set to `null` and the 'Send notification' request will not run. However, if the condition *is* indeed true, then the request will run and you will receive a notification on the respective channel.